# Difference in jquery selector $('#names') and $('input#names')

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a checkbox declared in my html like this:

```
<input id="names" name="names" type="checkbox" value="1">One</input>
<input id="names" name="names" type="checkbox" value="2">One</input>
<input id="names" name="names" type="checkbox" value="3">One</input>
```

I thought `$('#names')` will give me handle to all the checkbox elements but it doesn't, however `$('input#names')` does.

```
$('#names').length is 1.
```

and

```
$('input#names').length is 3
```

Why is the difference?
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Urbw5/8/

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: It's invalid to use the same ID for multiple elements. Use `class` instead.

Comment: Don't reuse Ids. I bet you wouldn't like it if somebody else was using your SSN. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is immaterial, [`id` values ***must*** be unique within a document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#concept-id). If you need to group the inputs, you'll have to use something other than `id` (`class` is frequently [over]used for this, but you can do it structurally as well — for instance, all `input` elements within a given container).

The reason for the difference in the results you're seeing lies in how jQuery's selector engine (Sizzle) optimizes. If you pass in a simple ID-based selector, Sizzle uses `document.getElementById` (and then checks that what it got back really has that `id`, because of bugs in IE prior to IE8). So it returns one element.

But if you pass in a compound selector like `input#names`, it doesn't follow that optimization path and actually does a DOM search (either directly in its own code, or via `document.querySelectorAll` if the browser supports it). Usually that involves searching for all matching elements first (e.g., all `input` elements), and then filtering the list according to the other qualifiers. So it happens that on your test browser, either Sizzle or the browser's selector engine isn't short-circuiting that selector even though it should know that having found one matching element, that's all it needs to do.

Answer (score 4):

One reason is that this isn't valid HTML. id elements must be unique. So it doesn't surprise me that jQuery is giving you odd results. If you want all the "names" checkboxes, you probably want:

```
$("input[name='names']")
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('#names')` causes jquery to use `getElementById` which obviously return a single element, whereas `$('input#names')` will do something like : `getElementsByTagName` and then using loop find only those which has id as `names`

Answer (score 2):

`input#names` searches for an input element with a `names` id.
`#names` searches for any element with a `names` id.
But as you can't use the same id for more than one element in a page, that'd be the problem. If you need it more than once in a page, use classes.
http://jsfiddle.net/FrxN8/

Answer (score 2):

That inconsistancy occurs because you use multiple IDs.

And ID by dfinition is unique. There should be exactly one of any ID on a given document. You shouldn't put many elements with the same ID. There's a class name for that.

Also, on a side note, the `<input>` element should not contain anything (not even text nodes).

```
<input class="names" name="names" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input class="names" name="names" type="checkbox" value="2">
<input class="names" name="names" type="checkbox" value="3">
```

and then `$('.names').length = 3` and `$('input.names').length = 3` as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your HTML is invalid. `id` values have to be unique in a document. The correct way to achieve this is to use `class` instead:

```
<input class="names" name="names" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input class="names" name="names" type="checkbox" value="2">
<input class="names" name="names" type="checkbox" value="3">
```

And use jQuery:

```
$(".names");
```

Alternatively you could use an attribute equals selector to select by name:

```
$("input[name='names']");
```

Comment: That still isn't valid HTML as `<input>` elements should not contain text nodes. (and should not even have an end tag)

Answer (score 1):

As James says, it is invalid to have more than one element with the same ID.  This is what the name attribute is for.  It's strange that your second version works, but it must just be a quirk in jquery.

remove the id (unless you need it, in which case make sure they are unique).   Then do

```
('input[name="names"]').length
```

Unlike most people, I don't recommend using classes in this situation.  You're just bloating the dom with class names you don't use.  The attribute selector is perfectly valid here without adding classes you aren't using.

Answer (score 1):

James is right, HTML validation needs to use only an "id" only once. My guess is that jQuery is implemented to stop at first "id" found.

On the other hand, you're looking for "input" tags so jQuery knows he can find many tags. But it's not supposed to work anyway.

Use ".names" instead and you'll get same result for each test.

**EDIT:**
By the way,

$(".names") will look for every tag with class "names" whereas $("input.names") will look for only input tags with class "names".

Hope it helps.